# Enforcing that an object has specific kinds of methods?

Tags: java, oop, object, polymorphism

I am making a new class that accepts a list of objects as an argument.

However I want to make it so these objects can be anything as long as they have certain methods, for example a `.getValue()` method that returns a single `double`, or a `.getTimestamp()` method that returns a single `long`, etc.

Can this be done?

Comment: To require that objects have certain methods, program to the interface that has the methods. But are you really asking about *generic types*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use an `interface` or implementation inheritance,

```
 interface Foo{
   long getTimestamp();
 }

 class Bar implements Foo{
   ... impl ..
 }
```

And then your methods will take a List of subtypes of Foo ( the super type)

```
 void fn(List<? extends Foo> foos){
    for(Foo foo:foos){
      long time = foo.getTimestamp();
    }
 }
```

Comment: This works for custom classes, but it might be good to note that there isn't really a way of doing this for classes in libraries. The next best thing would be to use reflection to check if the method is declared in the class and throw a `NoSuchMethodException` if it isn't, which is messy.

Comment: So `List<? extends Foo> foos` means `fn()` only accepts a list of objects that extend the interface `Foo`?

Comment: Does the object class have to extend foo, as opposed to implementing it? Like can it be `List<? implements Foo> foos`

Comment: @user54089 In this case Foo is an interface and hence classes can only implement it, they can't extend it, only an interface can extend an interface

Comment: Right, but in your loop, it says `? extends Foo`. Does this not mean `?` is any object that extends `Foo`?

Comment: @user54089 this means you can pass List<Bar> to the method given that Bar implements Foo

Comment: Why isn't the syntax then `<? implements Foo>` since `Bar` is a class that implements the interface `Foo`?

Comment: @user54089 I am not the designer of the language :)

Comment: So it's a "that's just how it is" thing? In the answer below he passes the actual interface as the type? `List<MyInterface>`. Is this the same thing as `<? extends MyInterface>`? Could you have passed in `List<Foo>`?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using an interface, as long as you're defining these objects:

```
interface MyInterface {
    double getValue();
    long getTimestamp();
}

class MyClass1 implements MyInterface {
    @Override
    public double getValue() {
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public long getTimestamp() {
        // ...
    }
}

void someMethod(List<MyInterface> items) {
    for (MyInterface item : items) {
        double value = item.getValue();
        long timestamp = item.getTimestamp();
        // ...
    }
}
```

If you're not defining the class of these objects, there's no way to enforce it at compile time. Enforcing it at runtime could be possible with elaborate and ugly reflection hacks.

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces can help you regarding your question. You can have separate implementation for each of the following declaration you provide in it. 
Cheers. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want reflection. You have no control over the kind of objects that may be passed to your code, you just want to be able to check if they comply to  your standards. Right? And when they do, you want to be able to call the expected methods.

Search for "Java reflection".